# Equivalence of two topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=(0,\infty)$ be a space, $d_{1}(x,y)=\mid{x-y} \mid$ and $d_{2}=\mid lnx-lny\mid$ be two metric spaces. Show that these metrics generates the same topology.

My attempt:

$\tau_{1} \subset \tau_{2} \iff (\forall B_{d_{1}}(x,\epsilon)\in\beta_{d}) (\exists\delta>0):B_{d_{2}}(x,\delta)\subset B_{d_{1}}(x,\epsilon)$

$B_{d_{1}}(x,\epsilon)=(y\in X : d_{1}(x,y)<\epsilon)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$

$B_{d_{2}}(x,\epsilon)=(y\in X : d_{2}(x,y)<\epsilon)=(xe^{-\epsilon},xe^{\epsilon})$

EDİT:

I want to show that these metrics are Lipschitz equivalent.

We need to find $\alpha,\beta>0$ st $\alpha .\mid x-y \mid< \mid lnx - lny \mid<\beta . \mid x-y \mid$

Since the derivative of $ln$ is bounded in such space, we can say that it is Lipschitz, so there exists a positive number $\beta$ st. $\mid ln(x)-ln(y)\mid <\beta \mid x-y\mid$.

On the other hand, does there exist any $\alpha$ st. $\alpha .\mid x-y \mid< \mid lnx - lny \mid$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps you should use MVT

Comment: You need to find a $\delta>0$ such that $x-\epsilon \le xe^{-\delta}$ and $xe^{\delta} \le x+\epsilon$. This $\delta$ might depend on $\epsilon$ AND $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prove that for each $x \in X$ and each $\varepsilon \geq 0$, there exists $\delta \geq 0$ such that $B_2(x,\delta) \subseteq B_1(x,\varepsilon)$, and the converse.

So fix $\varepsilon$, and take $\delta = \min\{\ln(\frac{x+\varepsilon}{x}),\ln(\frac{x}{x-\varepsilon})\}$.
It follows that
$$xe^{-\delta}\geq xe^{-\ln(x/(x-\varepsilon))}=xe^{\ln((x-\varepsilon)/x)}=x\frac{x-\varepsilon}{x}=x-\varepsilon,$$
and 
$$xe^{\delta}\leq xe^{\ln((x+\varepsilon)/x)}=x\frac{x+\varepsilon}{x}=x+\varepsilon,$$
whence $$(xe^{-\delta},xe^{\delta}) \subseteq (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon).$$

Conversely, if $\delta=\min\{x(1-e^{-\varepsilon}),x(e^{\varepsilon}-1)\}$, you get that
$$(x-\delta,x+\delta) \subseteq (xe^{-\varepsilon},xe^{\varepsilon}).$$

Comment: Thank you but I have a question.

Don't we have to obtain xe^(delta) > x+epsilon instead of "<" ?

Comment: What do you mean, you have a question? Is that because you meanwhile edit your question? My answer only addresses the first (and original part).

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question just now.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you sooo much

Comment: @AYARcom No, notice how the inclusion of the balls in your question translates as the inclusion of intervals

Comment: @AYARcom OK. I don't know about the Lipschitz part which only appeared after I submitted my answer. If you're still interested in that part, and someone addresses that problem, perhaps you can accept that answer then in place of mine one; and if you do so, perhaps you will still acknowledge mine one by upvoting it. Good luck!